# Can't write into a RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I can't write in richTextBox or the textBox , whenever I start to write something it freezes my program. Any idea what it is ? I haven't changed anything in code or properties of the textBox.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    File.WriteAllText("TextFile1.txt", richTextBox1.Text);
  }

  private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    richTextBox1.LoadFile ("TextFile1.txt");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code to get better answer?

Comment: there if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading a file into the text box that you are writing in:

So get rid of this piece of code:

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    richTextBox1.LoadFile ("TextFile1.txt");
 }
```

Try moving it into the OnLoad method of the form (assuming you want the text box populated when the form opens):

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);

  richTextBox1.LoadFile ("TextFile1.txt");
}
```

The RichTextBox also has a SaveFile method.  It's not clear from your code if the "rich" text is important to the application.

Comment: So how do i get it the textbox to show the last saved entry when i debug the program ?

Comment: @user1849277 I updated the example.  By showing the last entry, I assume you mean loading the file into the control when then form opens up.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool _isLoading = false;

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_isLoading) return;
    _isLoading = true;
    richTextBox1.LoadFile ("TextFile1.txt");
    _isLoading = false;
}
```